Freeradius 3, how to allow upn login syntax against active directory?
I have a working freeradius 3.0 connected to active directory and an aruba access point.
users are able to login using cn@domain. e.g. tesuse@test.com. I'm now trying to also make it possible to allow userPrincipalName for login. e.g. test.user@test.com (cn cannot be derived from upn without doing an ldap lookup).
I've tried to fetch the correct user via ldap, and that part seems to work. But I have now idea of how to extract the user's cn and use that for authentication. I think this is needed for mschap to work correctly?
in global and inner-tunnel I have ldap enabled under authorize and in ldap I'm using the filter:
filter = "(|(cn=%{Stripped-User-Name})(userPrincipalName=%{User-Name}))"
I get this message in the debug log both with cn@domain and upn login: ldap: User object found at DN "CN=tesuse,OU=Users,DC=test,DC=com".

Been a while since I worked with this, but does your ldap module configuration have attribute retrieval configured in the update{} block? The cn is completely irrelevant in AD, it is only a display name – sAMAccountName is what the "real" NT username is, and if you have the ldap module fetch it into a RADIUS variable (perhaps even overriding Stripped-User-Name), I believe you could then reference it from the configuration of the mschap module?

(That aside, this is not a programming question, so it's very much not a Stack Overflow topic; it should go to ServerFault or something similar.)

In my environment cn equals sAMAccountName. The hard parts are the details. Like the exact syntax, and exaclty in what order it all needs to be to work.
If there's any documented case on how to do this it would be very much appreciated.
I've tried changing the user-name (and stripped-user-name) first thing in authorize in default and inner-tunnel and logging in with the same users upn. the ldap lookup works but eap fails with "eap: Identity does not match User-Name, setting from EAP Identity".
Sorry if its the wrong forum, can it easily be moved to the correct one?

I actually found a working example online: https://freeradius-users.freeradius.narkive.com/o9Q0TKAv/userprincipalname-with-ntlm-auth-trying-to-get-it-right
The parts I had missed was that custom variables had to be predefined in the dictionary like this:
freeradius/3.0/dictionary:
ATTRIBUTE AD-Samaccountname 3003 string
Then it could be set like this in ldap:
update {
control:AD-Samaccountname := 'sAMAccountName'
And finally mschap (ntml_auth) could use the value like this: --username=%{control:AD-Samaccountname}

I also use this ldap filter:
filter = "(|(cn=%{Stripped-User-Name})(userPrincipalName=%{User-Name})(mail=%{User-Name}))"
That allows cn@domain / upn / mail as login syntax. If needed cn can be replaced by sAMAccountName. In our environment upn prefix does not match sAMAccountName.
